# Populating ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> with JSON defining group or element by condition (trying to create data for expandable list in Android)

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm trying to create an Expandable List in Android (Java).

Question: How to populate the ArrayList of ArrayList of Services with data from JSON according to the conditions below?

I get data from Google sheets with JSON. In gsheets each row consists of NAME and PRICE. Some rows have 'null' for the PRICE value and should be treated as 'Group Name' row. All the rows after the row with 'null' in PRICE are 'Children' for that Group Name and should fall under the specified group. Group continues until the next row with 'null' in the PRICE field.

```
    private void processJson(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int r = 1; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            String price = columns.getJSONObject(1).getString("v");

            if (price == "null") {
                Group group = new Group(name, null);
                groups.add(group);
            } else {
                Service team = new Service(name, price);
                teams.add(team);
            }
        }
```

I have simple data object 'Service'

```
public class Service {
private String name;
private String price;

public Service(String name, String price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
```

and had another Class for group (just the same) and I was creating a simple list view (just free of group names), but now I realize I need to create ArrayList of ArrayList of Service and I'm really stuck in populating the array according to the condition: if 'price' = null - it is a group and all the elements following after should be stored in this group until another group is identified.

JSON Data Example (for clarification)

```
{ 
    "rows": [
        { "c": [ { "v": "group name A" },  { "v": null }] },
        { "c": [ { "v": "service name a1" }, { "v": "100.00" } ] },
        { "c": [ { "v": "service name a2" }, { "v": "200.00" } ] },
        { "c": [ { "v": "group name B" },  { "v":null } ] },
        { "c": [ { "v": "service name b1" }, { "v": "100.00" } ] },
        { "c": [ { "v": "service name b2" }, { "v": "200.00" } ] },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

So the Group Name should be captured as well.

Comment: Is there a question here? Because there's no question mark in your entire post, so I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas there is a question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create an additional class:

```
public class ServiceGroup {

    private String name;
    private List<Service> services;

    public ServiceGroup(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.services = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }
}
```

Rather than using a `List<List<Service>>`, you can now use `List<ServiceGroup>`, which allows you to track the group name but not deal with having a list that starts with a dummy item.

Once you have this class in place, you can use this to parse the json:

```
private void processJson(JSONObject object) {
    try {
        List<ServiceGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        ServiceGroup currentGroup = null;

        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int r = 0; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            JSONObject priceColumn = columns.getJSONObject(1);

            if (priceColumn.isNull("v")) {
                currentGroup = new ServiceGroup(name);
                groups.add(currentGroup);
            }
            else {
                String price = priceColumn.getString("v");
                Service service = new Service(name, price);
                currentGroup.getServices().add(service);
            }
        }

        ...
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Major differences from what you might have seen before are:

- `List<ServiceGroup>` replaces `List<List<Service>>`
- The `for` loop starts from 0 so that we can read the first group name

Comment: I've added clarification for the JSON data structure. Specific lines with 'null' in the price actually hold 'Group name' data to be used later for the expandable list.

Comment: @AndyT I updated my answer to use the JSON structure you posted

Comment: thanks. But where is the 'Group Name' is stored? That should be the line that is processed when IF statement is true. So should look like this? 

'...
JSONObject priceColumn = columns.getJSONObject(1);
   if (priceColumn.isNull("v")) {
 JSONObject group_name = columns.getJSONObject(0); >>> store as group name?
 currentGroup = new ArrayList<>();
 groups.add(currentGroup);
     } else {...'

Comment: @AndyT I updated my answer to address storing the group name.

Comment: I accept your answer. I had to make one change to the **if** closure as price value is "null" and not just null.

`for (int r = 1; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
   JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
   JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");
   String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
   String price = columns.getJSONObject(1).getString("v");

   if (price == "null") {`

It might not be beautiful or effective, but it works! Now need to beat the BaseExpandableListAdapter to eat this :) I'm guessing I can pass **groups** right after passing the JSON